# Overlay a background image onto the web page

Tags: height, background-image

I'd like to add an image to the web page down the y-axis. This image would need to repeat, so I thought a background image would work best. As you'd expect I'm having trouble telling the CSS how tall the page is, especially with dynamic content from WordPress.

```
<div class="overlaid-image"></div>

<section class="green">Section content</section>
<section class="red">Section content</section>
<section class="blue">Section content</section>
```

I put together a fiddle to help explain: http://jsfiddle.net/15wc2noe/

Currently, unless I give the DIV a specific height, it won't travel down the full length of the page.

The goal is to get the repeating image to follow down the y-axis of the page to the bottom, without hard coding the height.

Comment: Probably not the best solution, but you can use a jQuery workaround to get rid of the problem like this: 
`$(function(){
    $("#overlaid-image").css('height', $(document).height());
});`

Comment: I think that works really well. http://jsfiddle.net/15wc2noe/5/ Any reason it's not the best solution? Other then it's JS dependent?